# Send mail with attachments saved in Postgre with Flask - using Mailgun

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, mailgun

I am using the following code to send emails

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35zOT.png)

But I need to know how to send files (PDF or JPG) stored in Postgre database.

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not as an image.  Text in images cannot be read by screenreaders and is notot searchable.

Answer (score 0):

```
comprobantes = Documentacion.query.filter_by(
            referencia=referencia2, notificacion="Comprobante").all()
        
        listacomprobantes = []
        listacomprobantes2 = []
        #print (listacomprobantes)

        for x in comprobantes:
            print(x.nombre)
            
            data = BytesIO(x.img)
            encoded_img_data = base64.b64encode(data.getvalue())
            image = encoded_img_data.decode('utf-8')

requests.post(
                "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/***s",
                auth=("api", "****"),
                #files=[("attachment", ("prueba.pdf", open("prueba.pdf", "rb").read()))],
                data={"from": "****@gmail.com",
                      "to": [para],
                      "subject": titulocorreo1,
                      "html": html,
                      })
```